# create dependent dropdownlist i snot working using PHP mysql AJAX

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, dropdown

I have a PHP code that retrieve data from MYSQL database and includes these retrieved data into a dropdown list where 2 dropdown list exist, the user select from the first one and based on his selection the second one will display the related data.

- tbl_country:

  - country_id
  - country_name
- tbl_state:

  - state_id
  - state_name
  - country_id

can anyone tell me where the error in the code?

## code 1:

```
<?php

function load_country(){
  $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost","****","***","test");
  $output = '';
  $sql = "select * from tbl_country";
  $result = mysqli_query($connect,$sql);
 // var_dump($result);
   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
     $output.='<option value="'.$row["country_id"].'">'.$row["country_name"].'</option>';   
   }
   return $output;

}
?>

<html>
<head>
    <title>dropdown test</title>
    <script  src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $('#country').change(function(){
         var country_id = $(this).val();
         $.ajax({
            url:"dropdown_fetch.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:{countryId:country_id},
            datatype:"text",
            success:function(data){
                $('#state').html(data);
            }

         });
       });

    });

</script>
</head>
<body>
     <p>select owner 
     <select name="country" id="country">
     <option value="">Select country</option>
     <?php echo load_country(); ?>
     </select></p>
     <p>select state 
     <select name="state" id="state">
     <option value="">Select state</option>
     </select></p>

</body>
</html>
```

## code 2:

```
<?php
$connect= mysqli_connect("localhost","****","****","test");
$output = '';
$sql = "select * from state where country_id = '".$_POST["countryId"]."' ORDER BY country_name";
$result = mysqli_query($connect,$sql);
//var_dump($_POST["ownerID"]);
$output='<option value="">Select state</option>';
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) {
    $output.='<option value="'.$row["state_id"].'">'.$row["state_name"].'</option>';
}
echo $output;

?>
```

Comment: what error are you getting? can you post it?

Comment: @kampangala there is no error but the second dropdown just do nothing still display select state

Comment: Try and inspect the XHR object you sent and the response (request and response headers) e.g. via developer console. It is a nice way to start the debugging.

Comment: @OlowookereEmmanuel in the console this  error is displayed :

          **ReferenceError: $ is not defined[Learn More]  dropdown.php:7:2
 <anonymous> http://127.0.0.1/dropdown.php:7:2**

Comment: Then your ajax script is not loaded. Any error 404 in the network tab of the console?

Comment: @OlowookereEmmanuel in the network tab  i have these lines:
**GET 
http://127.0.0.1/dropdown.php [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 36ms]
GET 
http://127.0.0.1/jquery.js [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 0ms]
ReferenceError: $ is not defined[Learn More]  dropdown.php:7:2**

Comment: Your while have 3 brackets instead of 4, also do post your ajax

Comment: Make sure that the jquery.js exists in that path (i.e. your_site_root_folder/jquery.js). It means your jquery.js should be in the root directory of your site)

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile yes i aleady  add the missing one but still the same

Comment: You will hv to post the html code

Comment: Your console error indicates that jquery.js does not exist in the root directory  of your site, and you are using it in your code as if it exists there. Thus the error 404. Copy your jquery.js file to the root directory of your site

Comment: @OlowookereEmmanuel i had a problem with the jquery as you said ... so ia edit the javascript link... .
that fix the errors in the network console .
but still nothing happen between the 2 dropdown list

Comment: So now you have no more error 404 and no more '$ not defined?' error?

Comment: @OlowookereEmmanuel i fixed the problem . it was in the sql statement  of the code 2 .
thank you... can you make your comment as answer in order to upvote... can you help me i have second post that is related to the same problem but ON WordPress platform

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a syntax error in your while loop.
Fix the line in code 2:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)
```

to

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
```